# Any way to have multiple font, text size, etc. in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, fonts

As the title says, I don't know if there is any possible way to do things like
Bold, italics, fonts, text size in a batch file, and if I can have different values of them in the same file.

This is something that is probably not possible, but if it is can someone tell me how?

NOTE: I'm not looking to go into properties or what-not. I mean that it's something I can code in.

Comment: it's not possible

Comment: You can change the font/fontsize for the whole window, text color can be changed on a per character basis

Comment: jeb so I can change the text color separately? How?

Answer (score 3):

The two images below were created by a Batch file:

[image: Different sizes and colors]

[image: Different fonts]

The method used to create such images is fully described at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5266).

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention what kind of system the batch file should run on I'll give you the answer for the old style one, [ANSI.SYS information](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php) If you have a more modern system you might want to take a look at Powershell instead. [Information on Petri.com](https://www.petri.com/color-coding-with-powershell)