# Increase text size in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, text, text-size

```
echo HELLO EVERYONE
timeout 3 >nul
echo how's is going your day
```

I want that "HELLO EVERYONE" is size 20 and how's is going your day? in size 10

how can I do this in a batch script without changing changing cmd properties

Comment: [Please take a look here for a solution, then delete your question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324366/12343998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a HTA window that instead of a console application (save this as `.bat` file):

```
<!-- :

@echo off

mshta.exe "%~f0"

exit /b %errorlevel%
-->

<html>
<head>
<title>~~~~</title>
<!--meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"--> 
</head>
<body>

<font size="15"><b>HELLO EVERYONE</b></font>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML + "<p/><p><font size='7'>how&#96;s is going your day</font></p>";;
        }, 5000);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

check also figlet functions here: [How would I use some multi line ascii art as my characters for a counter? (batch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174465/how-would-i-use-some-multi-line-ascii-art-as-my-characters-for-a-counter-batch)